# IBM Cobol 6.3 Copy Replacing with pseudo-text

Tags: cobol

Cobol Reference Manual (6.3), on page 526, [affirms literally](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6SG3_6.3.0/lr/ref/rlcdscopa.html):

**Comment lines, inline comments, or blank lines** in pseudo-text-2 or partial-word-2 are copied into the resultant program unchanged whenever pseudo-text-2 or partial-word-2 is placed into the source text as a result of text replacement.

Is it possible to have an example of how to build such a pseudo-text?

Thank you.

Livio Felicella

Comment: I suggest to add a link to the online version of the manual entry you reference, and ideally also specify the format you ask about within the question (no need to show the full syntax, but the minimal one that describes your question).

Comment: http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/epubs/pdf/igy6lr30.pdf
p. 542

Answer (score 1):

```
       COPY MYLIB REPLACING ==some words== by ==
      * comment line

      * after an empty line
           DISPLAY 'DONE'. *> with inline comment
       ==.
```